# UITableView separatorStyle = none vs. separatorColor = .clear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, separator

Yesterday I took a look at a quite big project  from someone else and I noticed that wherever the intention was not to have the separator generated by UITableView, it is done by setting `tableView.separatorColor = .clear` instead of `tableView.separatorStyle = .none`.

Now I wondered If there might be a reason for that.. Is the result any different or does changing the style property mess up the constraints somehow because 0.5p are missing?

Comment: I think both are the same to hide the separator. BTW changing the style or the color of the separator doesn't change any thing related to constraints so don't worry.

Comment: check apple documentation : 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614909-separatorstyle and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614984-separatorcolor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are thinking in right direction.

`tableView.separatorColor = .clear` // It clears the separator background color

`tableView.separatorStyle = .none` // It removes the separator from superview(`UITableCell`)

**Case Study:**

Consider height of `UITableViewCell` is set to 50.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```

If there are a `UILabel` in `UITableViewCell` and you have provided the **leading, trailing, top and bottom** constraint then `tableView.separatorStyle = .none` will not cause any constraint-break as height of `UILabel` will be auto-increased.

But if above case if you have applied **height-constraint** as well, then there will be difference of **0.5 pixel** in calculated height and constraint height.

It is not necessarily happen every-time but to prevent this condition, we should use `tableView.separatorColor = .clear`.